# How can I make my configuration available regardless on which machine I am working on?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, vimrc, bashrc

I have created a custom `.vimrc` and `.bashrc` in my local machine.
Also I have a couple of `vim` plugins that I find useful. Now I `ssh` remote servers to work very frequently. But each time in order to work I need to spend/lose some time copying my local environment so that I can work (i.e. `.vimrc` etc).
I was wondering is there a way for me to not have to do this but somehow my configuration become available/"visible" in each remote server I `ssh`?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a git or mercurial repository with your custom scripts e.g. in `~/myscripts`. Clone it to where it is needed. Also, add a script to create symlinks to the myscripts directory in your home directory `~/` and maybe a script to pull changes from everywhere and update.

Well, adapt it to your own needs...

Comment: +1.Interesting.Requires some work in areas I am not really familiar, but seems doable.

Comment: if ssh is already in place, git or mercurial take only a few commands to learn, to get you started. http://hgbook.red-bean.com/ or http://git-scm.com/book. A good tutorial for Mercurial is also http://hginit.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Like pvoosten, i suggest keeping a git repo. I've put an alias into my .bashrc to clone that and then run a script which symlinks the ~/homedir files back to that repo checkout.

It's **super** quick and dirty, but looks a little like this (feel free to improve - i suggest doing something like an `ls ~/repo/home/ | grep -v setup-links.sh` dir listing in setup-links.sh to avoid the need for the crappy filePaths=):

You could also make the .bashrc alias use ssh and scp to work remotely on the machine and avoid both steps 2 and 3 below, but it works for me anyhow.

It means you can do:

1. ssh-copy-id (host) *setup password-less ssh*
2. scp .bashrc (host) *copy your bashrc over*
3. ssh (host) -A *login to the host and forward ssh agent*
4. setuphome *does a clone of the git repo, and sets up the links*

Obviously don't put your ssh keys into the git repo, or gpg keyring

.bashrc (which is itself in git and after step 4 will become a symlink):

`alias setuphome='git clone (your git repo) ~/repo/home && cd ~/repo/home && ~/repo/home/setup-links.sh 2>/dev/null remove ; ~/repo/home/setup-links.sh make 2>/dev/null; cd ~'`

setup-links.sh

`filePaths=".bashrc
.tmux.conf
.vimrc
.bash_profile
.gitconfig
.ssh/config
.vim"
if [ "$1" == 'make' ]; then
    echo 'Making links'
    for filePath in $filePaths; do
        grep '/' <<< $filePath >/dev/null && mkdir -p $(dirname $filePath) 2>/dev/null
        ln -s $(pwd)/$filePath ~/$filePath 
    done
elif [ "$1" == 'remove' ]; then
    echo 'Removing links'
    for filePath in $filePaths; do
        unlink ~/$filePath
    done
else
    echo 'Error, $1 should be "make" or "remove"'
    exit 1
fi`

Answer (score 0):

Keep your stuff in a git repo which includes a script for setting things up.

As an example, here are my dotfiles:

https://github.com/wincent/wincent

And this is the script I run to "install" them:

https://github.com/wincent/wincent/blob/master/bootstrap.rb

There are plenty of other repos on GitHub if you just search for "github dot files".